# Video does not play after Encode

Tags: azure, html5-video, azure-media-services

I upload a video to azure, create an asset, and encode the video. When the encoding is finished I get four files in an asset folder (.ism, .mp4, .xml, .xml) and the links to each source. When I try to play the .mp4 file in a video player nothing happens.  However when I download the .mp4 file it works fine.

```
<video id="video1" src="https://123media.blob.core.windows.net/asset-bf389cc4-8454-410a-9492-7acab59b2d25/Wildlife_H264_4500kbps_AAC_und_ch2_128kbps.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" height="400" width="600" />
```

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount1 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient1 = storageAccount1.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var context = new CloudMediaContext("123media", "###############################");
        var CreateAsset = context.Assets.Create(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), AssetCreationOptions.None);
        var assetFile = CreateAsset.AssetFiles.Create(fileName);

        IAccessPolicy writePolicy = context.AccessPolicies.Create("Policy For Copying", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), AccessPermissions.Write | AccessPermissions.List);
        ILocator assetLocator = context.Locators.CreateSasLocator(CreateAsset, writePolicy, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));
        string assetContainerName = (new Uri(assetLocator.Path)).Segments[1];
        CloudBlobContainer assetContainer = cloudBlobClient1.GetContainerReference(assetContainerName);
        CloudBlockBlob assetBlob = assetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        assetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(blob);

        var inputAsset = context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id == CreateAsset.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (inputAsset == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not find assetId: " + CreateAsset.Id);
        var encodingPreset = "H264 Broadband 720p"; // <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129582.aspx#H264Encoding">http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129582.aspx#H264Encoding</a>
        IJob job = context.Jobs.Create("Encoding " + inputAsset.Name + " to " + encodingPreset);
        IMediaProcessor latestWameMediaProcessor = (from p in context.MediaProcessors where p.Name == "Windows Azure Media Encoder" select p).ToList().OrderBy(wame => new Version(wame.Version)).LastOrDefault();
        ITask encodeTask = job.Tasks.AddNew("Encoding", latestWameMediaProcessor, encodingPreset, TaskOptions.None);
        encodeTask.InputAssets.Add(inputAsset);
        encodeTask.OutputAssets.AddNew(inputAsset.Name + " as " + encodingPreset, AssetCreationOptions.None);
        job.Submit();
        job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

Comment: -deleted-, added as answer

Answer (score 1):

One reason why you might not be able to play the video will be, you haven't added a Streaming Endpoint on your media services account.
Assign at least one unit to be able to stream your video online. That did the trick for me.
Find it here.

[image]

Also, follow the blog by [MingFei Yan](http://mingfeiy.com/windows-azure-media-services-useful-resources). Very useful when starting with Azure Media Services.

Answer (score 0):

If your asset publicly available by that URL - try to add type='video/mp4' to the video tag.

Side note - also you need to 'publish' video so it'll be stream-able via shared 'encoding units' - your .ism file indicates you've created some kind of Streaming public asset (Smooth one I guess).

Keep in mind that streaming is not yet fully supported in all browsers (MPEG DASH is HTML5 streaming format) and for other streaming formats (Smooth or Apple HLS) you'll need to use Silverlight \ Flash implementations.

Comment: Yes I have tried adding video/mp4 to the video tag. It does not make a difference. I also tried playing the video in the Media Services Content Player inside the Azure Portal and I get an error message saying "We are unable to connect to the content required.". I am not getting an error on any part of my script and like I said in the original post, when I download the MP4 File it works fine.

Comment: What encoding preset had you used ? Is it published ?

Comment: Yes it is published. I edited my original question to include the encoding code.

Comment: 2 cents: 
I think this code executes asynchronously -  assetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(blob) 
so when you trying to create encoding task- your input file might not yet fully copied.
2nd - you said you published it - publishing code is not included here, so are you creating SAS or streaming urls ?

Comment: I did not think of that. I will change the code and see if that makes a difference. To publish it, I went to the media services control panel in Azure and clicked on publish. I have not written the publish code yet.

Comment: Ok, this adds a bit. When you clicked on publish in Azure portal in Media tab - you was actually publishing streaming url, it's not SAS(shared access signature) and I think there is no way to create SAS from portal UI any more. To play video in video tag - you must supply direct file link - so you can create SAS manually or store file in public blob and link directly (haven't tried this one tbh - creating read only SAS is pretty simple).feel free to drop me an email if you need any detailed help (alexey at shcherbak.me

Comment: I added a publishing script after encoding and it works. I guess you can not encode it and then publish it from the portal. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You are right - you can't publish video to play in the video tag. Portal publishes only Streaming URL, thus used in Silverlight\Flash players which are capable to play streaming content. Video tag at this moment can't play streaming video and you have to provide SAS urls, which are effectively - direct links to your files with some policies, so you need to generate them in code.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things with Azure Media Services.

First of all, although Azure Media Services works directly with Azure Storage, I strongly advice you to not work directly with the underlying storage (although you technically can). The reason is - you will very fast loose control what is available to public, and what not. Even more - you can potentially break the Assets - Blobs links and cause inconsistency in your Media Service.

Second, the correct way to play an MP4 result into Video element is by providing the Full path to the MP4 assest with a [Shared Access Signature Locator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974308.aspx). The containers and blobs which Media Services is using are marked as private and no public access is allowed. So, you need a locator. And when you want to just see the result in a Video element, you need a Shared Access Signature locator that points to the MP4. This will be progressive download video play, but it will play.

Last, but not least, never forget ([from docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974308.aspx)):

> There may be a 30-40 second delay after a Locator is created to when
>   it is available for use. This issue applies to both SAS URL and
>   OnDemandOrigin locators.

So you need a logic to manage your locators. As far as I remember, and if it is still the case, there is limit of the number of locators (or access policies) you can create per asset.